# Google .NET Library Can not use with release mode

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

every one:
   I met a problem,i use Google library to login and upload video to Youtube,
   I develop at Debug mode,App can open Auth login page with:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource(60000);
            CancellationToken token = cancelSource.Token;
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(uri,
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
                    "user",
                    token);
```

but when i change to release mode,code exception,like blow:

nSystem.AggregateException: AggregateException_ctor_DefaultMessage ---> System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException: Reflection_InsufficientMetadata_NoHelpAvailable: EETypeRva:0x00018688. For more information

have some one know the reason?i research on google found that somebody said it is because of .net Native Complie problem,is right?

Comment: Have you found a solution?